# Go example won't run

Tags: testing, go

I'm trying to add an example to a package, and run the example via `go test`, however the example is never run.

For example, see this gist: https://gist.github.com/85469ecc65bb5bb85857

The gist has `example_test.go`:

```
package cow_test

import (
    cow "gist.github.com/85469ecc65bb5bb85857"
)

func Example() {
    cow.Poke()
}
```

Yet when I run this:

```
# go test -v example_test.go 
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  0.002s
```

However other packages from stdlib work just fine:

```
# cd /usr/lib/go/src/errors
# go test -v example_test.go 
=== RUN: Example
--- PASS: Example (0.00s)
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  0.002s
```

What is wrong with my example?

Comment: You should [read the documentation about testing](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/) .. you have here some fundamentally wrong things that you should cover prior to attempting to write tests.

Comment: ...I linked to the documentation for you... ?

Comment: Your comment is basically a "RTFM" comment without any specific examples of what is wrong or where to focus. I see absolutely nothing in the scenario I have provided that goes against the testing documentation. Certainly nothing "fundamental".

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Please see the accepted solution. The only thing wrong was missing a step.

Comment: @Patrick RTFM can be a perfectly valid answer. Questioners are expected to do research and read the basic relevant documents and to not be [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Comment: @DaveC Except in this case I obviously had read the documentation, while Simon hadn't. If he had provided any additional info, this would have been apparent, and saved everyone headache.

Comment: Opened a chat for further discussion on the topic: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74004/29313626 . @SimonWhitehead, you are invited if you wish.

Comment: @Patrick Re-reading this.. it appears I upset you and I definitely did not intend to. I will pick my words with more care next time .. and also take more time to interpret the question better. I originally read this as "I have this example, it doesn't work. Why not?". I have added a comment into your chat also.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Examples):

> Example functions without output comments are compiled but not executed.

Add an output comment:

```
func Example() {
    junk.Poke()
    // Output: MOOOO!
}
```

Comment: Apparently it is also important **not** to have a space between the Output and the ":". Putting it here in case someone else accidentally adds space there and then wastes an hour figuring out why it doesn't run.

Comment: It's also important to ensure the `// Output: ` comment is the last comment.

Comment: You may also put the actual output in a separate comment line after the line of `// Output:`

Comment: maybe for clarification: if the example does not output anything, a final `// Output:` without any output also sufficies.

Comment: Heads up, does not work without the semicolon.